# Two Manifest file for single Application?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

My apps requirements are such that i want to create two AndroidManifest files both will have some common activities and some unique activities. can i have two manifest files for single application?

Comment: Why do you need two manifest files for a single app? Do you mean you want to publish two different versions of your app, each containing a common set of activities, but also some unique activities?

Comment: It really doesn't make sense.

Comment: i would like to maintain same code , My issue is this i have two launcher activities in the single application and for some requirement i need both launchers and for other only one.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** One app can have only 1 manifest.

If you want more then you need more apps. If you like some common functionality that is shared between two apps, you can declare a third android project as a `Library` project and reference it in both of the other apps. The library will also have a manifest of its own.

Thanks I got my solution...

Answer (score 0):

First: One app can have only 1 manifest. if you want more then you need more apps. if you like some common functionality that is shared between two apps you can declare a third android project as a Library project and reference it in both of the other apps. the library will also have a manifest of its own.

Comment: But the Applications Manifest will overwrite the library manifest, **not** merge with it.

Comment: Yes That is correct. i forgot to mention that. thanks @Blundell

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It is better to find out which activities to run in your software. You can always check the OS version or device capabilities in your own app and decide your path and functionality on the runtime.